# Proving that the polynomial of a normal function is normal

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a polynomial $Q(X)\in K[X]$, a normal linear function $f:V\rightarrow V $ that qualifies for the spectral theorem,i.e there exists an orthogonal basis of $V$ that consists of eigenvectors of $f$. Let $t_1,t_2,... ,t_r$ denote the corresponding eigenvalues. Furthermore let $p_j: V\rightarrow V$ denote the orthogonal projection onto the eigenspace of $t_j$.

I have already shown that I can write $f$ and $id_V$ as: $$f= \sum_{j=1}^r t_jp_j \ \ \ \ \ id_V = \sum_{j=1}^rp_j$$

I would now like to show that $Q(f)$ is a normal map as well and that $Q(f)$ can be written as $Q(f) = \sum_{j=1}^rQ(t_j)p_j$

I have already tried doing this by simply writing down definitions, but this does not get me very far: 
$$Q(f) = Q\Big(\sum_{j=1}^r t_jp_j\Big) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} a_i \Big(\sum_{j=1}^r t_jp_j\Big)^i$$

but this is where I get stuck.I know that for a projection $p$:  $p \circ p = p$, i.e $p^i=p \forall i\in \mathbb N$, but I do not know how to simplify the exponentiation of that sum. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more straightforward to use the true definition of a normal operator.  Note that $f$ is normal if and only if $ff^* = f^*f$, where $f^*$ is the adjoint.

Suppose that $Q(z) = \sum_j a_j z^j$. From there, we note that 
$$
[Q(f)][Q(f)]^* = \left(\sum_{j} a_jf^j\right) \left(\sum_k \overline{a_k} f^{*k}\right) = 
\sum_j \sum_k a_j\overline{a_k} f^jf^{*k}
$$
Since $f$ commutes with $f^*$, we can show that this is the same as $[Q(f)]^*[Q(f)]$.

---

If you must prove your statement using the spectral theorem: it will help to note that $p_ip_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$, from which it follows that
$$
\left(\sum_j t_j p_j\right)^i = \sum_j t_j^i p_j^i
$$

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks a lot